# Magento 2 : How to Render Product List?

Tags: magento2, product-list

I am new in Magento 2. I need to render product list, and I'd like to use existing templates etc.

I found this: [get the html of a product as it would render in category page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94708/get-the-html-of-a-product-as-it-would-render-in-category-page)

But it is for Magento 1.9, and not very specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

Copy the child block `search_result_list`from the file `vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml` into the root block tag of your own layout file.

In the block file, add a `getProductCollection` method:

```
public function getProductCollection(){

    // Replace with your own logic.
    $productIds = ['123', 'abc'];

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $model = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $collection = $model->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $productIds))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->load();

    return $collection;
}
```

In the template:

```
<?php

    // Show products
    $this->getChildBlock('search_result_list')->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());
    echo $this->getChildHtml('search_result_list');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository.  You will use the getList() function to get the list of product models needed.  The tricky part is setting up the Search Criteria.  You will pass in the list of product IDs that you already have as a part of the criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about the Search Criteria, but what I am missing, is the rendering part, not the search.